# UITableView set seperatorColor with clear background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with `backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`.

In my `tableView` I've got cells with different `backgroundColor`. Some of them have a  `clearColor` background as well. Now I want to set a general color (not `clearColor`) for the `seperatorLine` which doesn't seem to work with a clear `tableViewBackgroundColor`.

Comment: What do you mean by "doens't seem to work", the setter doesn't set new value, the separator color doesn't change, the new color doesn't look like you expected ?

Comment: the seperator color is clear. It doesn't matter which color I choose

Comment: Are you sure there's a 1px (might be 2px on new devices) space reserved for separator or is it just missing ? Did you set its style to none and forgot about it ? Try view debugging to see the real views structure.

Comment: I can see the the background of the parentView of my tableview.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to get rid of the separator, you can do that like this:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

To me this more clearly describes what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

ok! I am an idiot....

I didn't see that I was setting

```
tableView.separatorEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
```

later in the code.... embarrassing